# Failed to install Truffle on MacOS Mojave

Tags: truffle, nodejs, npm

I am currently really struggling in getting Truffle up and running. I am running MacOS Mojave and have Node (v.10.16.0) and NPM (6.9.0) and have tried

> npm install -g truffle

and have gotten:

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>
> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>
> npm ERR! code EACCES
>
> npm ERR! errno -13
>
> npm ERR! syscall access
>
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
>
> npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
>
> npm ERR!   stack:
>
> npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
>
> npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>
> npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
>
> npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
>
> npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
>
> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
>
> npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/*myname*/.npm/_logs/2019-07-09T21_08_31_313Z-debug.log

And when I try

> sudo npm install -g truffle

I get:

> Password:
>
> npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/truffle
>
> npm ERR! code EEXIST
>
> npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/truffle: /Users/vikas/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/truffle symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local/bin
>
> npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/truffle
>
> npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/robertocantu/.npm/_logs/2019-07-09T21_13_07_178Z-debug.log

If you know what I can do, please explain it as simple as possible. I am not too well versed in doing things in Terminal; I'm just trying to learn how to program smart contracts and I can't seem to even set up my computer to do so.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can some one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the npm documentation for resolving eaccess permissions when installing packages globally.
https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

I would suggest resolving the permissions issue using a node version manager.
Note: Currently truffle doesn't work with node 12 so use either node 10 or node 11.

---

You don't have to install truffle globally.  I generally install it locally `npm install truffle` and then run using npx, `npx truffle test`.

https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b